# Wait for an element in Protractor

Tags: protractor

My Protractor test is failing when I'm trying to click a button.

In my application first button is disabled. This button enables after clicking another button.

I need a way to wait Protractor until the button is enabled. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You better try the answer [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38171249/how-to-wait-in-protractor-till-the-element-is-enabled)

If you need a quick and direct answer try this.

```
var elm = element(by.id('paynow-info-btn'));
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(elm), 5000);
elm.click();
```

Hope this helps :)